# How to find out who run sudo command?

Tags: shell, scripting, sudo

I want to know which user has run the command

```
sudo -udelpoy sh abc.sh
```

When I echo `whoami` inside `abc.sh` I receive `deploy` as the user but I want to know which user has run the `sudo` command on first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-m` option of `who` to get this info:

```
julien> whoami
julien
julien> who -m
julien   pts/4        2014-06-25 13:42 (:0)
julien> sudo su
root  > whoami
root
root  > who -m
julien   pts/4        2014-06-25 13:42 (:0)
```

If you only want the username, use `awk`:

```
who -m | awk '{print $1}'
```

From the manpage of `who`:

```
-m     only hostname and user associated with stdin
```

Comment: My who -m command is empty. What happened?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches for that.

- **Who run sudo :**

Look the variable **$SUDO_USER**

- **Who is logged :**

Look the variable **$LOGNAME**

(here we don't know who run sudo but who is logged. Sometimes, people prefers this approach)